# Improving performance of moving arrays into an array

Tags: python, performance, array

I am loading a bunch of arrays and putting them into a single array.  The loading of the data is negligible, but putting it into `combinedArray` takes significant time (as in this code).

```
import time
import numpy as np
start_time = time.time()

   st,en = 0,0
   combinedArray = np.empty(shape = (30000*30000))
   #Get the array that each process wrote to
   for i in range(10):
       #load the array
       #ex loading 
       X_np = np.empty(shape = (30000*30000)/10)
       st = en
       en += np.shape(X_np[:])[0]
       #add to the array list
       combinedArray[st:en] = X_np[:]

   print("Array Calc:",time.time()-start_time)
```

What I have found is often someone talking about not using append, so I tried with creating the array first, but just moving it is time consuming.  Any advice on how to optimize this is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I performed some timings of the solutions presented by [@AustinHastings](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/106818/) in his [answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/220877/92478) on my machine at work (Linux 64bit, Intel Core i7-2600, 16GB RAM, Anaconda Python 3,
).

The timing function was slightly modified to use repetitions get more accurate results as well as to easier get the timings for visual display.

```py
def time_func(f, shape=1000, n_reps=10):
    global COMBINED_SHAPE
    COMBINED_SHAPE = shape
    start_time = timeit.default_timer()
    for _ in range(n_reps):
        ca = f()
        assert np.shape(ca)[0] == COMBINED_SHAPE
    average_time = (timeit.default_timer() - start_time) / n_reps
    print(f"Time for {f.__name__}: "
          f"{average_time * 1000:.6f} ms")
    return average_time

# the functions go here

def perform_benchmark(*shapes):
    results = np.zeros((len(shapes), 5))
    for i, shape in enumerate(shapes):
        print(f"shape: {shape}")
        print(f"array size: {shape * 8 / 1024**3:.3f} GB")
        results[i, 0] = time_func(orig, shape=shape)
        results[i, 1] = time_func(concat, shape=shape)
        results[i, 2] = time_func(block, shape=shape)
        results[i, 3] = time_func(stack_ravel, shape=shape)
        results[i, 4] = time_func(stack_flatten, shape=shape)

    plt.figure()
    plt.plot(shapes, results, marker="o")
    plt.xlim((shapes[0], shapes[-1]))
    plt.grid(ls="--")
    plt.legend(["orig", "concat", "block", "stack_ravel", "stack_flatten"])

    plt.figure()
    plt.loglog(shapes, results, marker="o")
    plt.xlim((shapes[0], shapes[-1]))
    plt.grid(ls="--")
    plt.legend(["orig", "concat", "block", "stack_ravel", "stack_flatten"])

    plt.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    perform_benchmark(
           100000,    300000,    500000,
          1000000,   3000000,   5000000,
         10000000,  30000000,  50000000,
        100000000, 300000000
    )
```

The array size of \$500 \times 10^6\$ elements which would have come next was to big to fit in RAM and lead to excessive swapping (your original would be at \$ 900 \times 10^6 \$).

When looking at the linear plot you will see no difference between the solutions on all but `stack_flatten` which consistently takes about twice the time of the other solutions.

[image: double linear plot]

In an loglog graph you can see this as an approximately constant offset between `stack_flatten` and the other solutions.

[image]

These findings seem to be consistent with what Austin Hastings presented in his answer.

Answer (score 2):

I tried some alternative approaches, and got this result:

```
Time for orig: 0.15900921821594238
Time for concat: 0.18401050567626953
Time for block: 0.16700983047485352
Time for stack_ravel: 0.1760098934173584
Time for stack_flatten: 0.32501864433288574
```

It's worth pointing out that I'm on a 32-bit machine with not enough RAM to hang with you. So I used smaller arrays. You'll want to correct the code and try for yourself. Also, my validation is really minimal, so you should probably improve that as well.

```
import time
import numpy as np

COMBINED_SHAPE = (3_000 * 3_000)

def time_func(f):
    start_time = time.time()
    ca = f()
    assert np.shape(ca)[0] == COMBINED_SHAPE
    print(f"Time for {f.__name__}:", time.time() - start_time)

def load_partial():
    partial = np.empty(shape=(COMBINED_SHAPE // 10))
    return partial

def orig():
    st, en = 0, 0
    combined_array = np.empty(shape=COMBINED_SHAPE)

    for i in range(10):
        X_np = load_partial()
        st = en
        en += np.shape(X_np[:])[0]
        combined_array[st:en] = X_np[:]

    return combined_array

def concat():
    ca = np.concatenate([load_partial() for _ in range(10)])
    return ca

def block():
    ca = np.block([load_partial() for _ in range(10)])
    return ca

def stack_ravel():
    ca = np.stack([load_partial() for _ in range(10)])
    ca = np.ravel(ca)
    return ca

def stack_flatten():
    ca = np.stack([load_partial() for _ in range(10)]).flatten()
    return ca


if __name__ == '__main__':
    time_func(orig)
    time_func(concat)
    time_func(block)
    time_func(stack_ravel)
    time_func(stack_flatten)
```

Comment: Just to make sure I am understanding, the time just shows the original is faster?

Comment: Yes, it shows the original is faster on my horribly old machine. I'd strongly suggest running the timing framework on the actual hardware you intend to use, since it's *very likely* to have different performance characteristics.